# Component has no route config. in Component - Angular 2 Routing Error

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, typescript1.7

I'm very new to Angular 2.0 (who isnt!?!?!) and I can't get my routing to work! I keep getting the error '`Component "LoginComponent" has no route config. in [['/Register'] in LoginComponent`'.

This is my `@RouteConfig` and bootstrap code (to prove I am injecting the dependancies) taken from my `boot.ts` file

```
bootstrap(LoginComponent, [
    ROUTER_PROVIDERS, HTTP_PROVIDERS
]);

@RouteConfig([
    {path: '/login', name: 'Login', component: LoginComponent, useAsDefault: true},
    {path: '/register', name: 'Register', component: RegisterComponent}
])
```

This is my LoginComponent code... from my `login.component.ts` file

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {FORM_DIRECTIVES, FormBuilder, ControlGroup, Validators} from 'angular2/common';
import {RouteConfig,  ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, ROUTER_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/router';
import {Http, Headers, Response} from "angular2/http";

@Component({
    selector: 'login',
    templateUrl: 'app/login/login.component.html',
    directives: [FORM_DIRECTIVES, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})

export class LoginComponent {

    loginForm:ControlGroup;
    http: Http;
    userNotFound: boolean;

    constructor(fb:FormBuilder, http: Http) {
        this.loginForm = fb.group({
            'email': ['', Validators.required],
            'password': ['', Validators.required]
        });

        this.http = http;
        this.userNotFound = false;
    }

    login(event: Event, val:string):void {
        // stuff happens here
    }

    forgotPassword() {
        // stuff happens here
    }
}
```

and here in my view I have a link to a different part of my application. Taken from my `login.component.html` file

```
<a (click)="forgotPassword()">Forgot Password</a>
<br>
<a [routerLink]="['/Register']">Register</a>
<br>
<div class="error" *ngIf="userNotFound">
   User not found. Please try again...
</div>
```

However in the browser I get the following errors:

> EXCEPTION: Component "LoginComponent" has no route config. in
>   [['/Register'] in LoginComponent@23:19]
>
> ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: Component
>   "LoginComponent" has no route config.
>
> ORIGINAL STACKTRACE: Error:
>   Component "LoginComponent" has no route config.

Can anyone see what the problem is exactly? The default works and the everything is fine until I introduce the `<a [routerLink]="['/Register']">Register</a>` hyperlink. I've been trying to work this out for a while!

Here is my project structure (if it helps)...

[image: project structure]

Comment: where is your `<router-outlet>` and second thing angular2 is expecting routing from LoginComponent but unable to found.

Comment: You're bootstraping the wrong component. Your root component is `LoginComponent` therefore when you write `/SomeComponent` (absolute path) it will start from `LoginComponent` which has no RouteConfig.

Comment: I had a similar issue with nested routes.  The explanations on this issue helped. https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8420

Answer (score 1):

Actually upto i can understand the problem is in the routing file because you are Bootstrap the login component file and you are doing your routing in the boot.ts file. but instead you have to do routing in the loginComponent file because angular2 find routing in the bootstraped file i.e in your case is boot.ts but when you write

```
<a [routerLink]="['/Register']">Register</a>
```

this will look in the login.component.ts file for the routing. but unable to find tht's the error i think. and secondly import  which is not mentioned in the question i think.

use your parent routing in the logincomponent file, i hope this will help.

Comment: I realised that I should have used routerLink. I have moved the @RouteConfig into the LoginComponent - I still get the error!

Comment: now whats the error after moving @RouteConfig into logincomponent ? is the error is same or changed ? and check for the proper import path for the registerCompoent. is it correct or not.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar error, maybe if you, move this code

```
@RouteConfig([
    {path: '/login', name: 'Login', component: LoginComponent, useAsDefault: true},
    {path: '/register', name: 'Register', component: RegisterComponent}
])
```

inside of LoginComponent file.

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {FORM_DIRECTIVES, FormBuilder, ControlGroup, Validators} from 'angular2/common';
import {RouteConfig,  ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, ROUTER_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/router';
import {Http, Headers, Response} from "angular2/http";

@Component({
    selector: 'login',
    templateUrl: 'app/login/login.component.html',
    directives: [FORM_DIRECTIVES, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})

export class LoginComponent {
..//
```

---

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
    import {FORM_DIRECTIVES, FormBuilder, ControlGroup, Validators} from 'angular2/common';
    import {RouteConfig,  ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, ROUTER_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/router';
    import {Http, Headers, Response} from "angular2/http";

    @RouteConfig([
    {path: '/login', name: 'Login', component: LoginComponent, useAsDefault: true},
    {path: '/register', name: 'Register', component: RegisterComponent}
    ])

    @Component({
        selector: 'login',
        templateUrl: 'app/login/login.component.html',
        directives: [FORM_DIRECTIVES, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
    })

    export class LoginComponent {
    ..//
```

I hope this helps you, and sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 0):

Hi probably a bit late but i think the issue was probably that your name reference was incorrect. The link should have been as below removing the forward slash.

```
<a [routerLink]="['Register']">Register</a>
```